# When are the Windows hooks added to the hook chain

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I am trying to add a Windows hook to the hook chain and wondering when exactly it is added?

I am performing actions in this order:

1. I start any program and attach a debugger to it, adding a breakpoint on DllMain and callback functions of my injected code;
2. I inject the global hooks;
3. I programatically toggle visibility of a window - here I hit the DllMain function;
4. I hit the breakpoint on a hook callback as soon as I make window a foreground window.

Is there a way to trigger adding a hook callback to a window callback chain without making window a foreground window?

Thanks!

Comment: You are asking one question (*"When is a hook installed into the hook chain?"*), but are apparently interested in finding an answer to a different one (*"when does the system load the module containing the hook procedure?"*). Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the hook is added to the hook chain during the call to `SetWindowsHookEx`. The DLL is not necessarily loaded right away - the OS decides when it is. The hook itself is obviously only called when the hook chain is called, and this depends on the hook. If you hooked `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and your callback wasn't called until some point, that means there wasn't any message to hook. Therefore if you only wanted to intercept messages there is no problem. If you really think something is wrong, please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are some triggers.

If the type of your hook is `WH_GETMESSAGE`, you can perform a `PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST...` call to force any GUI processes to load the dll with the hook procedure in.

For other type of hook, you can have a try.